# Can Crashlytics check NDK crashes in the library we are using

Tags: android-ndk, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

we are using Crashlytics but sometimes there're crashes not being reported.

out project doesn't have NDK codes but we're considering are these crashes related to libraries we're used.

we're using several libraries including old NDK codes .

So can Crashlytics checkout the libraries NDK crashes ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are the libraries ones you've written or external 3rd party libraries? Also, are the libraries crashing the app or causing a caught, handled exception?

Comment: hi, @MikeBonnell . thanks for replying . The libraries are external 3rd libraries. And, It's hard to say the 3rd libraries causes crashes, but we indeed got crashes not reported by Fabric or ourselve's crash-report tool. So we wonder maybe   these crashes are caused by the 3rd libraries as they have some old and not stable codes.

Comment: Gotcha, if the library is causing a fatal crash within your app, then the crash should come through. However, you mentioned your own crash reporting tool and I wonder if there is a conflict between the two. Can you share Logcat output from after this type of crash happens?